# Plugins cannot find their css styles in folder

Tags: javascript, css, plugins, filepath, file-not-found

I've downloaded this template: http://themeforest.net/item/-medic-medical-health-and-hospital-html5-theme/8331329 from themeforest. Original template has **/plugins/** folder in root folder. I moved this folder into **/assets/plugins/** and included it in HTML like this example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
```

The javascript files are found, but plugins are still requesting their css files from original folder **/plugins** and not in **/assets/plugins/**, for example:

```
http://www.scsppza.local/plugins/royalslider/royalslider.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I can't found where is path to css files defined for those plugins. Is it possible to fix it somehow?

Comment: Why am I getting vote-downs? Is this wrong formulation or what? I would really need a solution.

Comment: I guess this is something you should be asking themeforest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the assets/css/style.css file and change the @import urls!